# Not able to build Angular JS application integrate with Angular 4

Tags: angularjs, angular, maven

I have a Angular JS application where each angular JS library files are included in html file for each functionality.Is it feasible to make this application work together with Angular 4.

Steps to make Angular JS work with Angular 4

1)install the @angular/upgrade How do I do make this work in sync with the old Angular JS files

2)I read it in a post that I need to define this in system.config.js

```
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js'
  }
});
```

3)In app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

4)main.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp'], { strictDi: true });
});
```

Are these steps sufficient to integrate Angular JS application to Angular 4.If so how do I do a build.The existing process is a monolithic application with Maven Build?Can Angular 4 be integrated with Maven?

Answer (score 0):

The official Angular website has a migration guide [here](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)

The old versions of Angular (AngularJS 1.x) have a completely different project structure to the new Angular >2. This guide should help you out.